# debug in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an performance issue in my stored procedure and because of that my procedure is taking to much time to complete execution. I want to debug my procedure.Is there any tool for this or any inbuild option available in sql server.I am using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in option. If you are using SQL Management Studio you already have this option. Just place a breakpoint at the **EXEC** command and debug the SP with **Alt + F5**.

Don't forget to step into your code by proceeding with F11.

For more information you can check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701(v=vs.103).aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

You can check either pressing `ctrl + L` or enable by Menu Query -> "Display Estimated Execution Plan" gives `execution plan of your query` or you can use `sqlprofiler` for this. Both gives you idea about which portion take time.

Debug will give when your logical error comes.

For your issue , you can check your variable by query in the some portion where you want to intermediate result `select @var1, @var2 or print @var1`